Cannot login to Openshift using password and username flag
I am having an issue where I cannot login to openshift via cli.
I keep receiving this error:
Login failed (401 Unauthorized)
Verify you have provided the correct credentials.

Command:
oc login <myopenshifturlwithport> -u "myusernamehere" -p "mypasswordhere"

I am using the Sandbox environment. Logging in via the Web ui works fine. The url from above is copied from the login instructions.
Reason i need this is to use the github action oc-login, but with my user credentials instead of a service account, as there is no option to use an SA with the sandbox environment.
ommitting the password seems to work, but how does that make sense? Is there no password check?
oc login  -u "myusernamehere"
